# How to break a single line in CSV to multiple lines using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Input:

> This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for
> professional and enthusiast programmers~It's 100% free~This is a
> collaboratively edited question and answer site for professional and
> enthusiast programmers~It's 100% free~

Output:

> This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for
> professional and enthusiast programmers~
>
> It's 100% free~
>
> This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for
> professional and enthusiast programmers~
>
> It's 100% free~

I don't want to replace the delimiter but just to split the text. How do i do it using JS.

Comment: By the way, you need to press enter twice for an empty line to appear in a question.

Answer (score 1):

```
let str = `This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers~It's 100% free~This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers~It's 100% free~`

console.log(string.split("~").join("~\n"));
```

Comment: .join("~\n") will preserve the ~ like asked for in the question.

Comment: Not the way it’s written in the answer, the mismatched `”` and `’` delimiters is a syntax error.